# SASS function / operation with vh

Tags: css, sass

I'd like to create a scss function to calculate the root font-size depending on the viewport width.

This

```
html {
  font-size: calc(14px + 30 * ((100vw - 320px) / 680)); 
}
```

returns `font-size: 14px;` which is the size I want. But the function I am writing:

```
@function root-font-size-function($viewport) {
   // $viewport: 1px * $viewport;
   $size: calc(14px + 30 * (($viewport - 320px) / 680));
  @return $size;
}
:root {
  font-size: root-font-size-function(100vw);
}
```

returns an error:

[image]

How can I write this sass function correctly?

Comment: You need to interpolate these variables within `calc`: `calc(#{$viewport})`

Comment: Thanks, this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Vivick, this works when interpolating the `$viewport` variable like this:

```
@function root-font-size-function($viewport) {
   $size: calc(14px + 30 * ((#{$viewport} - 320px) / 680));
  @return $size;
}
:root {
  font-size: root-font-size-function("100vw");
}
```